# Ruby 2.5 and FactoryBot raise TypeError

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I'm in the process of upgrading a Rails (5.1) app from using Ruby `2.3.3` to Ruby `2.5.0`.

I have the following FactoryBot (`4.8.2`) factory

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :training do
    transient do
      assigned_instructor { create(:user) }
    end

    description 'training description'
    instructor  { assigned_instructor }
  end
end
```

The users factory looks like

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:full_name)    { |n| "John Doe#{n}" }
    sequence(:email)        { |n| "john.doe#{n}@example.com" }
    role  { create(:role, activities: [create(:activity, name: 'activity')]) }
  end
end
```

When I run any spec that creates a `training` I get

```
Failure/Error: assigned_instructor { create(:user) }

TypeError:
coerce must return [x, y]
```

This does not happen if I create the user and pass it to the factory as below.

```
create(:training, assigned_instructor: create(:user))
```

Is there any change in Ruby 2.5 I should be aware of?

FYI, all the specs that create users work as expected.

Comment: The code shown here looks reasonable. In fact this stripped down case works beautifully with ruby 2.5: https://gist.github.com/momolog/d0725d3aa232c65a9328f832b88819e1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I'm not sure how to interpret it. Everything works fine with Ruby 2.3.3 but when I upgrade to 2.5 I got the error. From your comment, it seems the issue is not related to 2.5.

Comment: It looks like it's not caused by the shown FactoryBot setup in combination with ruby 2.5 but rather a problem in the rest of your rails app. More specifically there *seems* to be a `coerce` method for some numeric defined somewhere, that does not return a two-element array [as it should](https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2011/01/25/class-coercion-in-ruby).

Comment: A stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: I have been able to fix the issue by updating as `assigned_instructor { build(:user) }`. Not sure why this works but unfortunately, I don't have time for a further investigation now. Thanks for the time.